# select specific elements of second dimention of a 2D array

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list like this in python:

```
a = [[5, -4, 6], [9, 0, 6], [20, -1, 9], [6, 5, -7]]
```

and I have a `b` array such as this one:

```
b = [0, 1, 2, 0]
```

how can I get this list?

```
[ a[0][b[0]], a[1][b[1]], a[2][b[2]], a[3][b[3]] ]
```

I should mention that the lengths of `b` and `a` are both variables `n`.
I know that I can make a list with a loop with these values, but I'm looking for a syntax (something like map) for this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It seems you already have your answer

Comment: `[ai[bi] for ai, bi in zip(a, b)]`

Comment: @GalAbra I wanted to know is any elegant way to do this or not.

Comment: @jdehesa I think you should post this as an answer

Comment: Why would you want not to use a loop ?

Comment: @KamranHosseini Please take a look at my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick way with `zip` is:

```
a = [[5, -4, 6], [9, 0, 6], [20, -1, 9], [6, 5, -7]]
b = [0, 1, 2, 0]
result = [ai[bi] for ai, bi in zip(a, b)]
print(result)
# [5, 0, 9, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), you can do:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [[5, -4, 6], [9, 0, 6], [20, -1, 9], [6, 5, -7]]
>>> b = [0, 1, 2, 0]
>>> arr = np.array(a)
>>> arr[np.arange(len(a)), b]
array([5, 0, 9, 6])
```

Comment: What is numpy?  What does it do?

Comment: @KamranHosseini numpy is a python library does a lot of stuff with arrays and numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [[5, -4, 6], [9, 0, 6], [20, -1, 9], [6, 5, -7]]
b = [0, 1, 2, 0]

c = list(a[i][b[i]] for i in range(len(a)))
#or c = list([ai[bi] for ai, bi in zip(a, b)])
print(c) #return [5, 0, 9, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `map` and inside it use `lambda` and `zip`:

```
a = [[5, -4, 6], [9, 0, 6], [20, -1, 9], [6, 5, -7]]
b = [0, 1, 2, 0]
print(list(map(lambda x: x[0][x[-1]], list(zip(a,b)))))
```

Output:

```
[5, 0, 9, 6]
```